# Grails Rateable Plugin is not saving rating in database

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.0, gsp, grails-domain-class

I am new in Grails. I am using [Rateable Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rateable) for integrating User Rating function in my grail application. I am doing like this ...

Installation

```
grails install-plugin rateable
```

my Post.groovy Domain class ---

```
package groovypublish

import org.grails.twitter.Person
import org.grails.rateable.*

class Post implements Rateable {

static hasMany = [comments:Comment]

String title
String teaser
String content
Date lastUpdated
Boolean published = false
SortedSet comments
Person author

static searchable = [only: 'title']

static constraints = {
    title(nullable:false, blank:false, length:1..50)
    teaser(length:0..100)
    content(nullable:false, blank:false)
    lastUpdated(nullable:true)
    published(nullable:false)
}
}
```

Tag i am using in my _post.gsp file ...

```
<rateable:ratings bean='${post}'/>
```

My Rating star is showing like this ...

[image]

When User give rating then it showing like this ..

[image]

**But Rating is not saved in Database.**

When I again refresh page then it showing (0 Ratings). I don't know why my rating is not saved in db. I am using [Spring Security Core Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core) for Authentication purpose. Any Suggestion ???

**UPDATE** : ---

I added `grails.rateable.rater.evaluator = { request.user }` line into my Config.groovy file. But It showing ERROR :

```
URI
  /groovypublish/rateable/rate/1
Class
  org.grails.rateable.RatingException
Message
  No [grails.rateable.rater.evaluator] setting defined or the evaluator doesn't evaluate to an entity. Please define the evaluator correctly in grails-app/conf/Config.groovy or ensure rating is secured via your security rules
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Spring Security Core Plugin for Authentication purpose

In which case you probably want something like

```
grails.rateable.rater.evaluator = {
  grailsApplication.mainContext.springSecurityService.currentUser
}
```